# Conditional Greying out rows

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a spreadsheet (spreadsheet1) with values in a column like

```
--- Cake 
flour
sugar
water
--- Candy
sugar
flavor 
--- Soda
sugar
water
flavor
```

And in another spreadsheet (spreadsheet) in the same book I have

```
     Pulldown(cake,candy,soda)  Pulldown(cake,candy,soda)  Pulldown(cake,candy,soda)
flour
sugar
water
flavor
```

What I want to do is when I select a value form the pulldown menu I want the rows available that are listed in spreadsheet1, i.e. I pull down candy then sugar is candy are editable value but flour and water are greyed out. Spreadsheet1 is dynamic so the values may change.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with dependent data validation. The second drop-down will not grey out the values, but simply not list them at all. You need to create named ranges for each option in the first drop-down and name them the same as the selected value. Then use Indirect() when assigning the range name to as the data validation list source. These range names can be set up to be dynamic, using dynamic formulas instead of fixed ranges.

For more details see Debra Dalgleish's article http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html